# Excel VBA: Alternatives to "Application.Union" across sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

Below are two examples of code that I'm hoping to incorporate into one macro but I know Application.Union has its limits. I tried setting up an AllAreas and Idx type of deal but couldn't get the syntax correct for the ranges. Could someone please take a look at this and let me know how best to condense it into one macro? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("GL").Range("D1:D2000")
    If cell.Value = "Computer Checks" Then
        If MyCount = 1 Then Set NewRange = cell.Offset(0, 1)
        Set NewRange = Application.Union(NewRange, cell.Offset(0, 1))
        MyCount = MyCount + 1
    End If
Next cell

For Each cell In Worksheets("BS").Range("D1:D2000")
    If cell.Value = "CHECK PAID" Then
        If MyCount = 1 Then Set NewRange = cell.Offset(0, -3)
        Set NewRange = Application.Union(NewRange, cell.Offset(0, -3))
        MyCount = MyCount + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do, not so much the code but in broader terms? I take it you understand that `Union` doesn't work across sheets, but it's not exactly clear what you want to do with `NewRange` or `MyCount`.

Comment: If Union across sheets *did* work, then what would you be doing with that range?

Comment: Hi. Thank you both for replying!

I'm looking for a specific phrase in a cell and if Excel finds it, I'm having it paste data from specific columns in that row into specific columns in a consolidated summary sheet. Like for instance if any of the cells in column D in the sheet named "GL" have the phrase "Computer Checks" in them, I'm pasting the date, the journal entry number, the payee, the check number, and the amount elsewhere. The other example is the other side with more or less the same information. I can then use formulas to check for a match between the data sets.

Comment: Do you want to paste the data from GL sheet in the consolidated sheet, then the data from BS sheet under the GL data, and so forth? If so, just write the data after looping through the sheet. Alternatively, you can load data directly into an array, then write the array to the consolidated sheet when done.

Comment: They're side by side columns so that I can "show the work" and have it be easily interpreted by others. My goal is to have one big macro so that they don't have to remember which order to do them in. I want co-workers to see what data is needed to do the cross check but don't necessarily want them to start cutting and pasting or vlookup'ing the workbook to hell because that leads to data falling through the cracks.

Comment: I presume you hope to save time by creating a range of preselected cells, effectively excluding unqualified cells from further processing. However, by processing row by row you could have finished the job with the same effort it takes to create the Union range.

Comment: My goal is to find all the checks in a general ledger, find all the checks in a bank statement, paste them in a separate checks reconciliation tab, and then paste the resulting checks issued but not yet cashed into a separate outstanding checks tab. There's ways to do this manually and using vlookups or index/match but one is prone to error and the other requires a user that has a good grasp of intermediate formulas. The macros might have extraneous language but I haven't been provided with an alternate solution that does what I need with minimal end user input.